Geometric structure of the output of a random weight neural network fed with random data
Take a model with random weigths:
const create_model = () => {
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [10], units: 4, activation: 'sigmoid' }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [10], units: 16, activation: 'sigmoid' }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: 'sigmoid' })); // Output layer
        return model;
    };

Draw random data from a normal distribution and compute the output of the random-weights NN:
const size = 25000;

const model = create_model();

const generate_points = async () => {
    const inputs = tf.randomNormal([size, 10], 0, 10); 
    const outputs = model.predict(inputs); 
    const points = await outputs.array(); 
    inputs.dispose(); 
    outputs.dispose(); 
    return points;
};

If you draw this output, it will look like some kind of hyper-cube 2D projection (see examples here https://imgur.com/a/tBZKeYf).
Why do hyper-cubes "emerge" from random data/random weights, and what kind of NN architecture would lead to such structures?

As a baseline, is this just because activation: 'sigmoid' is bounded in $[0,1]$ ?

How does it lead to hypercubes? Sorry, beginner here.

There's a bunch of values that are pushed to 0 and 1? If you plug a multivariate gaussian into a sigmoid, you're going to get something like that, I think?
